# Wanting to return ALL categories of product but only returning those passed into query

Tags: postgresql, ecto, elixir

My select query returns one distinct product, and a list of categories that the product has. However, it only returns the categories that are in the `^categories` list passed into my query, even if it actually has another 5 categories. I want to return ALL the product categories, even if there is only 1 category in the `^categories` list which is passed in to the function:

```
  def create_query_no_keyword(categories, shop_ids) do
    products_shops_categories = from p in Product,
    distinct: p.id,
    join: ps in ProductShop, on: p.id == ps.p_id,
    join: s in Shop, on: s.id == ps.s_id,
    join: pc in ProductCategory, on: p.id == pc.p_id,
    join: c in Subcategory, on: c.id == pc.c_id,
    where: c.id in ^categories,
    where: s.id in ^shop_ids,
    group_by: [p.id, p.name, p.brand],
    select: %{product: p, categories: fragment("json_agg( DISTINCT (?, ?)) AS category", c.id, c.name), shops: fragment("json_agg( DISTINCT (?, ?, ?)) AS shop", s.id, s.name, s.point)}
  end
```

Why does the returned product only return one category if only one category is passed into the above function, when the product actually has 8 categories?

Schemas (the `product_categories` actually uses a `Subcategory` - just named differently):

```
 schema "products" do
    field :name, :string
    field :brand, :string
    field :description, :string
    field :image, :string
    field :rating, :integer
    field :number_of_votes, :integer
  end

  schema "subcategories" do
    field :name, :string
  end

  schema "product_categories" do
    field :c_id, :integer
    field :p_id, :integer
  end

  schema "shops" do
    field :name, :string
    field :place_id, :string
    field :point, Geo.Point
    field :geo_json, :string, virtual: true
    field :distance, :float, virtual: true

    timestamps()
  end

  schema "product_shops" do
    field :s_id, :integer
    field :p_id, :integer
  end
```

Comment: Because `where: c.id in ^categories`. Is there a reason you are not using a preload?

Comment: @JustinWood I thought that would mean it will only select products which have a category in the list `^categories`, but return the whole product and its categories.

Comment: Can you post your schemas, at least the relevant bits, and maybe we will be able to tell you what you need to do to get the information out that you want?

Comment: Is there any reason you are not using a preload?

Comment: @JustinWood No reason, I just did what I thought I should do. I'm new to ecto. Would preloads work with my schemas?

Comment: Currently not. If you used `has_many` / `has_one` / `belongs_to` instead of things like `field :p_id, :integer`, you would be able to use preloads.